# Assigning values to variables in separate scripts with Python and Pygame

Tags: python, class, variables, pygame

I need to create a variable in a different script from the main one in my game I am working on, with [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) and [Pygame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame).

For example:

```
def test():
    a = 10
def testing():
    return a
```

Then I run code like this:

```
import (script name)
script name.test()
script name.testing()
```

And after this, it gives an error. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note: *it doesn't work* is a terrible problem description. Please be clear in your problem descriptions and include any error messages you see.

Comment: This is also a very basic question; do read the Python tutorial again; names inside a function are local and are not seen by other functions.

Comment: @Endoro: It is not a duplicate because one of possible answers to this question is to make an object `Test()` that encapsulates the value `a` then `t.test()` computes  `self.a` and `t.testing()` can return it. It scales if there are many variables computed in `test()`. A practical example would be a configuration object that has a method to compute default values and methods to retrieve such values. "Scoping rules" won't suggest such answer.

Answer (score 1):

'a' in testing() is not a global variable and hence it's not recognised from previous function test(). If you really want to use 'a' from test() then you can probably define 'a' as Global Variable.

Comment: ok, ive herd of this before but not sure how to do it